# Given these points can I determine the curve?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometry

### Background

Let us define a function $f(x)$

$$ \sum_{r=1}^n f(r) = g(n) $$

Now we know there must exist a $k$ such that:

$$ g'(k_n) = \frac{g(n+1) - g(n)}{(n+1) -n} = f(n+1) $$

Such that $n\leq k_n \leq n+1$

### Question

Given we know that **$g(n)$ is expressible as the sum of the function $f(x)$** and we are also **given the set of points $(k_n,g(k_n))$ does it form a unique curve**? How can we determine the curve $y=g(x)$?

Comment: You need to rephrase your question, which function is given, and which one you define?

Comment: You aren't given any function ... you are given "the set of points $(k_n,g(k_n)$" and you know $ g(n) $ is expressible as a sum of $f(r)$

Comment: Function $f$ doesn't give you any info, since you always can take $f(x) = g(x) - g(x+1)$. Given $n$ points on the curve defines unique polynomial of degree $n-1$, by interpolation, Any other class of functions gives you infinite number of solutions